# How can I rewrite the code to open link on Chrome custom tab?

Tags: java, android, webview, imageview

So I have this code in my mainActivity that I use to open the link, but it opens in chrome app and I want it to open in custom-chrome-tabs webView option.

```
ImageView playtowin;

playtowin = findViewById(R.id.ptw);

    playtowin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gotoUrl("https://www.xbox.com/pt-BR/play");
        }
    });

      private void gotoUrl(String s) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri));
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the guide here [custom-tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/integration-guide/)

first add the dependencies to your app/build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
   ...
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"
}
```

your solution should look something like this.

```
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent;

ImageView playtowin;

playtowin = findViewById(R.id.ptw);

playtowin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openCustomTab("https://www.xbox.com/pt-BR/play");
    }
});

private void openCustomTab(String url) {
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
}
```

Comment: ok that worked for me, also i tried to change the color but it says for me that cannot resolve the symbol "intentBuillder". code -> int colorInt = Color.parseColor("#66bb6a");
        CustomTabColorSchemeParams defaultColors = new CustomTabColorSchemeParams.Builder()
                .setToolbarColor(colorInt)
                .build();
        intentBuilder.setDefaultColorSchemeParams(defaultColors);

Comment: If the previous answer helped can you please approve it? Your question in the comment is not very clear. Please post it as a separate question.

Comment: ok, it worked i'll approve thanks